# Power BI API not returning all data sources

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, powerbi-rest-api

I'm using postman to query the power bi api:
[https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/{{gatewayId}}/datasources](https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/gateways/%7B%7BgatewayId%7D%7D/datasources)

And its not returning all the data sources.  I'm thinking it may be a paginated or limited result set that is returned, but I can't find anything about this in the api docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/gateways/get-datasources

Is there anything missing in the docs or how I should use the API to get a full list of data sources for a gateway?

Thanks in advance!